# Program wtih recursive function and without global variable - C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a program which looks for path in 2-D array which "cost" is the lowest. Here's an example (start: a[0][2] -> end: a[3][0]):

```
10 10 1 10 
10 10 1 10 
10 1 10 10 
0 10 10 10 

1 -> 1 -> 1 -> 0
```

In my case, I need to go from row number 0 to row number 3 doing 3 steps (so three directions are available). You can choose column start number.

The problem is, I can't do that without using global variable (min2). I think I should use "int" not "void" recursive function then.

Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<climits>
using namespace std;

int a[4][4] = {10, 10, 1, 10, 10, 10, 1, 10, 10, 1 ,10, 10, 0, 10, 10, 10};
int min2=INT_MAX;
int k=2;         //column start number

bool can_go(int x, int y){
    if(x<0 || x>3 || y<0 || y>3)
        return false;
    return true;
}

void min_path(int x, int y, int steps, int result){
    if(x==3 && steps==3){
        if(result<min2)
            min2=result;
    } 
    else{
        if(can_go(x+1,y)){
            min_path(x+1,y,steps+1,result+a[x+1][y]);
        }
        if(can_go(x+1,y-1)){
            min_path(x+1,y-1,steps+1,result+a[x+1][y-1]);
        }
        if(can_go(x+1,y+1)){
            min_path(x+1,y+1,steps+1,result+a[x+1][y+1]);
        }
    }
}

int go(){
     min_path(0,k,0,a[0][k]);
     return min2;
}

int main(){
    cout << go();
}
```

Comment: which is doable. In each iteration, you just need to return the optimal value till now.  Then return to its caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by return the minimum value at each recursion call. The comparison operation then will be done in non-leaf nodes. In the original code, the comparison operation is done in leaf nodes (base case). The new function looks like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<climits>
using namespace std;

int a[4][4] = {10, 10, 1, 10, 10, 10, 1, 10, 10, 1 ,10, 10, 0, 10, 10, 10};
int k=2;         //column start number

bool can_go(int x, int y){
    if(x<0 || x>3 || y<0 || y>3)
        return false;
    return true;
}

int min_path(int x, int y, int steps, int result){
    if(x==3 && steps==3){
        return result;
    } 
    else{
        int min = INT_MAX;
        if(can_go(x+1,y)){
            int b = min_path(x+1,y,steps+1,result+a[x+1][y]);
            if (b<min)
                min=b;
        }
        if(can_go(x+1,y-1)){
            int b = min_path(x+1,y-1,steps+1,result+a[x+1][y-1]);
            if (b<min)
                min=b;
        }
        if(can_go(x+1,y+1)){
            int b = min_path(x+1,y+1,steps+1,result+a[x+1][y+1]);            
            if (b<min)
                min=b;
        }
        return min;
    }
}

int go(){
     return min_path(0,k,0,a[0][k]);
}

int main(){
    cout << go();
}
```